# Save files on Azure App Services and make them accesible from the outside

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, file-upload, download

I am new to Web-Development and have therefor maybe a beginner question.
So I am having a Web-App with an Angular Frontend und .Net backend, deployed on Azure.

Now users should be able to upload files (pdf, etc.) to the server which sould be stored permanetly. I would prefer to store them on a normal filesystem, so I don't want to use a database. Futhermore the files should be accessible for external services for futher processing.

I am not sure if that is possible with Azure App Services or if I need some other components. The only way I found to store files on the server is in the "wwwroot" folder. But I found no way to download them from the outside. Should I create a Web-API for that or do I think to complicated? Should I deploy my App somewhere else? What could be a way to implement this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Recommendation is to use blob storage to store these files and serve them from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Azure Storage**.

In Azure storage you can find mainly two options in your case. **Blob** and **File Storage**.

Blob is "more advanced" in a sense that it serves files on the browser, streaming video and audio etc.

File storage is a replacement of an on-premises file server.

Both options support file access by external services, and in addition to authorization, both are supported with Azure AD and shared access token.